# Rails accessing private methods using attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, private-methods, attr-encrypted

I'm trying to get `attr_encrypted` to obscure some data before saving it to the database. I need to deal with the logger output later, but at the moment I just want to get the field data from a submitted form, encrypt it, and save it.

Here's my model:

```
class Agreement < ApplicationRecord
  attr_encrypted :test_field, key: :encryption_key

  private

  def encryption_key
      ENV['super_secret_key']
  end
end
```

I notice that when I comment out `private` everything seems to work as expected. But I obviously don't want to give public access to that info (ya know: super secret key), so I *want* it to be private. However, when I include `private` I get an error. Specifically: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'bytesize' for :encryption_key:Symbol)`. What I've drilled down to is that `attr_encrypted` is throwing an error because it is not getting a key passed to it, because the private method is not being accessed properly.

In theory, in the `attr_encrypted` bit, I could just set `key: ENV['super_secret_key']` rather than calling a method, but the goal here is to actually create a new class with corresponding database table by which I can save, store, and rotate my keys, which in turn are obfuscated by an environment variable for an extra layer of security.

So my real question is: what's going on with my private methods, and why is `private` frustrating things, even within the scope of the model? I think I'm doing something very basically incorrect, but I've also followed examples from others that do this, so any guidance on my error would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the attr_encrypted call is at the class level, the encryption_key method is instance level. Try doing this instead:

```
class Agreement < ApplicationRecord
  attr_encrypted :test_field, key: ENV['super_secret_key']]
end
```

Admittedly untested, but it should work.

Really though the private won't secure it anymore. You did this right by loading it through env from a config file. So long as it's not hardcoded in your repository, that's mainly what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately that does not seem to do it. 1) What am I missing here (something obviously basic)? How can you tell that `attr_encrypted` is at the class level and the `encryption_key` is at the instance level? And why does removing `private` make it work? 2) Regardless of if this worked or not, why would private not secure it any more? Thanks!

Comment: I should have read the error more closely. You need to call the method and pass the result to attr_encrypted. So you could do: `attr_encrypted :test_field, key: encryption_key`. Notice i removed the symbol, and just have the method name there. But instead, since it calls once when the application loads up, why even have the method at all? So i updated my answer to just output env.

Comment: To answer your second question, keeping it secure will be to not expose it in any controller render calls. So long as you just access it within the models, it should be fine. Given it's in ENV[], you can access that anywhere in the app already.

Comment: Cheers! Much appreciated.